# Boolean Algebra help: duals

Tags: math, boolean, boolean-logic, boolean-algebra

I consistently keep getting this question wrong, and I cant figure out why

```
(a+b)(b+c)=ac+b
```

I put this as the answer:

```
ab+bc=a+cb
```

I do not understand why that is wrong

Comment: Aren't you supposed to be solving it? i.e. finding the possible values?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on the Mathematics Stack Exchange.

Comment: This is Boolean algebra which is completely different than regular algebra. I am supposed to be finding the dual of the first equation

Comment: I said this was Boolean algebra because it has to do with computer science

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about boolean algebra and [math.se] instead of programming or software development.

Answer (score 1):

```
(a || b) && (b || c) = (a && c) || b
```

It's written in c style (may be better for understanding). It means that if we have b = true the result is true, if b = false the result is depends of a and c in couple. Also we can find result for each tuple of (a, b, c) and for identical tuple we have identical results.